# php auto fill html table with blank data

Tags: php

I have a HTML table that's being filled with data from a query (php). I have two months of data displayed, sept and oct. Since we've only had 15 days in Oct, it shows a table of 30 rows for Sept and only 15 rows for Oct. How can I have it display 31 rows for October, and fill in the blank rows as the days come?

Current Code:

```
 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Hour</th>
 <th>Questions</th>
 </tr><br><br>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($questions))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['hr'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></td><td>";
```

My query is:

```
$oct_week = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(`dPostDateTime`) AS `day` FROM `tblQA` WHERE cCategory IN ('Football','Baseball','Basketball','Hockey') AND dPostDateTime >= '2010-10-01' AND dPostDateTime <= '2010-10-31' GROUP BY `day`");
```

Comment: How does your current code look like?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description.  Only the hours are coming out of MySQL, how do you know what dates are showing?  How do you know which date an hour is from?

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong query. I've updated for the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `date('t')` to get the number of days in the current month, then when doing your loop, keep a count of records printed for the current month. After printing the filled in values, simply subtract `$printedRecords` from `$daysInMonth`, and have a loop printing empty values for the remainder.

### Added after more code given in question

Assuming I'm reading your query right, change your code to this:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Hour</th>
<th>Questions</th>
</tr><br><br>";
$printedRecords = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($questions))
{
    $printedRecords++;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hr'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
$daysInMonth = date('t');
$toPrint = $daysInMonth - $printedRecords;
for ($i = 0; $i < $toPrint; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></td><td>";
```

Use `&nbsp;` to insert a space, force visible, or use BigMike's suggestion in CSS.

Comment: Without further explanation from BigMike this'll work for best guess of what wants.  Don't forget to set the CSS `table {empty-cells:show}` property for those cells.

Comment: Slokun, thank you. What this is doing is printing 31 additional blank spaces rather than knowing that 15 have already printed. it should only print 16 additional. Counter not working right?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. In the For statement, $i = $printedRecords